# How to assign value to attribute in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

How to assign value to custom attribute in angularjs as in code below.

```
    <tr ng-repeat="log in logs">
        <td>{{ $index }}</td>
        <td>{{ log.level }}</td>
        <td>{{ log.time | date:"MM/dd/yyyy 'at' h:mma"}}</td>
        <td>{{ srcFormatter(log.src.file, log.src.line) }}</td>
        <td><json-formatter json="{{log.msg}}" open="1"></json-formatter></td>
    </tr>
```

`log.msg` is containing json string which I need to assign to **json** attribute.

This is my first day working with angularjs, so please bear with me.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us the logs object?

I checked the json-formatter directive and expecting a json like json="{my: 'json'}"

Check the [documentation](http://azimi.me/json-formatter/demo/demo.html)

and last thing, standard attr assign like `value="{{log.msg}}"` It means your example is correct but I think problem is your object.

Comment: `{
    "REQ": {
        "interaction_type_id": "9",
        "initiator_id": "6725210406",
        "source": "NEWCONNECT"
    },
    "USERAGENT": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.75 Safari/537.36"
}`

Comment: I can't see msg object in here.

Comment: It's the value of log.Msg

Answer (score 0):

I have got the answer from author of json-formatter. The solution is to use "msg.log" as the attribute value.